# Network traffic not found in crittercism

Tags: crittercism

My mobile app is using Crittercism v5.8.7.  I am able to see the crashes, network traffic is not tracked in Crittercism.

I tried checking for isServiceMonitoringEnabled() and enabled the service using crittercismConfig.setServiceMonitoringEnabled(true), but still I don't see the network traffic.

I tried with both prod and test environment.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check our documentation https://support.apteligent.com/articles/knowledge_base/Why-my-application-not-showing-any-data-in-the-network-insight-section and make sure that the instructions are followed correctly.

In case you still have the same concern, please send us an email at support@apteligent.com. Do not forget to include the app name and the app ID in your email, as we require these details to locate your account in our database.